# Visual Studio 2008 Setup Project not deleting file when uninstalling

Tags: visual-studio-2008, setup-project

I marked an xml file permanent in my setup project. But now if I change in my setup and mark the permanent flag for same file to false...it still leaves it out as permanent....

Here are step to reproduce...

1. In setup project mark xyz.txt file's Permanent flag to true.
2. Install the product...
3. Uninstall the product
4. xyz.txt is there as expected...good.
5. Delete xyz.txt file manually
6. Change product setup project and now mark file xyz.txt file's Permanent flag to false.
7. Install product
8. UnInstall product
9. xyz.txt file is still there...Bad

Does anyone know how to clear the permanent flag?

Answer (score 0):

The permanent flag is set on a component. Once the component is installed and registered, future installer versions won't be able to remove the flag because the component is not uinstalled.

A solution is to remove the file and add it again to generate a new component for it. You can also try testing on a clean machine.